# Are there fuel cells for methane + oxygen? Could there be?

Tags: power, chemistry, methane, fuel-cell

Hydrogen + oxygen fuel cells powered the week-long Apollo missions to the Moon and Shuttle missions to orbit, and there is a industry trying to build itself around hydrogen-fed fuel cell-based road vehicles.

Cryogenic methane + oxygen deep space vehicles are probably coming, and missions could go well beyond Mars, to moons of Jupiter or Saturn possibly at some point, where solar power is only a few percent as strong as it is circa 1 AU. (see [How far from the Sun can solar power be used as a reliable energy source?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/623/12102)) Just look at Juno's giant solar panels and its [fear of eclipses](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/39177/12102) and Rosetta's [need to hibernate](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15374/12102) when furthest from the Sun for examples.

**Question:** There is hydrogen in methane, so there is some potential for a fuel cell, but I'd like to know if there are any designs or research into a methane + oxygen based fuel cell for electrical power.

Yes, there are also [proposed internal combustion space-engines](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25687/12102) and one could just use a natural gas powered electrical generator, but for the purposes of this question let's stick to conversion from chemical to electrical power using fuel cell technology.

Comment: Good question! **Answer:** Theoretically possible, but it's in the early stage of development. [This](http://artsandsciences.virginia.edu/cchf/research/fuelcells.html) might be helpful. Further in [Solid oxide fuel cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_oxide_fuel_cell), lighter hydrocarbons can be internally reformed. Simply methalox-based fuel cell is possible it's but under development.

Comment: @Intellex okay that's good news!

Comment: Note: the correct terms would be methox or hydrox, the fuel cell doesn't run on liquid oxygen and gaseous fuel. And usually the oxygen is left assumed.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff that's a really good point! The fuel cell doesn't know it's on an interplanetary voyage aboard a big rocket with cryogenic storage. It only sees gas phase reactants that are probably pre-heated before reaching the catalysts. I've adjusted the wording accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This 2018 release from Georgia Tech describes one such - claimed to be more practical than previous methane-fueled cells because it operates at a lower temperature. It is a solid-oxide cell.

It appears to work by catalytically cracking the methane to hydrogen, and it seems that the advance is in the cracking part.

https://www.news.gatech.edu/2018/10/29/finally-robust-fuel-cell-runs-methane-practical-temperatures

Comment: Thank goodness, it's about time somebody got cracking on this.